# How can I understand the zip2john hash format?

Tags: encryption, aes, password-cracking, brute-force

I had a .zip file that was apparently encrypted with AES-256 deflate.

```
7z l -slt archive.zip | grep Method
Method = AES-256 Deflate
```

Then I used zip2john to get a "hash" out of it:

```
archive.zip/archive/flag.pdf:$zip2$*0*3*0*5e6874b2503c8250b2a618543de2a650*bf56*28*cc4ffaa12a7b647a26a362049842f670145c797ed7e46aad1bede1fdd0a38c381bd5145d506580d8*bb716f7901735f090566*$/zip2$:archive/flag.pdf:archive.zip:archive.zip
```

I then used *john* and managed to crack it, but I'm not happy.

I want to understand a few things, **first of all how do I make sense of the output of the zip2john command** I know this is not "just" a hash, what are all those other field separated by ":" and "*"?

Regarding AES, am I right that the password we provide is used by a KDF to then generate the actual key? If that's the case is this weak password the reason **john** was able to crack this?

Comment: *"what are all those other field"* - See the documentation in the source code: https://github.com/openwall/john/blob/bleeding-jumbo/src/zip2john.c#L82

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thanks a lot Steffen